# Is saying “Woo!” makes apples falling from the sky? (what is the right answer to the groundless hypothesis?)

Tags: discussion, answers

Is saying "Woo!" makes apples falling from the sky?

This is obviously the wrong assumption, but most likely you will not be able to find any direct and trusted references that it *does not*. How the question of such kind should be answered? Argumentation about missing negative references is very frequent when defending various pseudo-scientific hypothesis.

Of course, such question could be closed. However it may exist a small opportunity that the direct evidence does exist somewhere and will emerge after a year or two. Still, should we just downvote/delete all answers claiming that the assumption unlikely to be correct?

One may start explaining about sound, gravity and and that apples unlikely to exist in the sky to start from. However it is always possible to say "this does not answer the question directly". Indeed, literally, it does not.

Or, similarly, if somebody asks "Do cactuses grow in Antarctica?", one may provide the scientific study about the distribution of cactus species and where they are likely to grow. However probably no any botanist ever wrote in the serious work "cactuses do not grow in Antarctica". Seems that providing some contextual information, even from the good sources, is not that this community wants.

If such questions should be edited/rephrased, how the question about falling apples should be rephrased? If such questions are invalid and should be closed, then under which criteria?

Comment: If some site started getting hundreds of thousands of hits with an article "MAKE APPLES FALL FROM THE SKY WITH THIS ONE WEIRD TRICK" and people were believing it, then yeah, someone should debunk that nonsense. We'd do it based on the specific detail of what the actual hoax article actually said (the actual claim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of question is *not notable* and will be closed.

From the point of view of the answers:

- if there is positive proof, the correct way to answer is "It is true, [evidence]"
- if there is negative proof, the correct way to answer is "It is false, [evidence]"
- if there is no proof, but there is evidence there is no proof (e.g. an expert opinion explaining why there isn't any proof), the correct way to answer is "We don't know, [evidence]"
- if there is only minor, controversial or unconvincing proof, the correct way to answer is "We don't know, but [evidence]"
- if there is no proof at all, we do not want any answer

Answers that merely rely on anecdotes, logic, original research, theory or opinion are going to be downvoted and deleted:

- It is true because [my personal theory]
- It is false because the burden of proof relies on the other side
- It is true because it happened to my cousin
- It is false because [my personal experiment]
- It is true because I think so

All of these answers are great on other sites, but on this site we decided to rely on (hard) evidence. If you are interested in debating the issues, which are sometimes interesting, please use our chat.